# Attach SQL server 2008 R2 mdf file on SQL server 2008 database

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I know that we can't restore sql server 2008 R2 .bak file on sql server 2008. But I was just wondering on whether we can attach SQL server 2008 R2 mdf file on SQL server 2008?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since R2 version of server is newer than your version of 2008, you will not be able to migrate directly, but you have a few options, in my order of preference:

- Upgrade to SQL Server 2008 R2 Edition - by far the simplest approach
- Use a third party product to replicate schema and then the data (e.g. Red Gate SQL Compare / SQL Data Compare).
- Use a manual script,
- Use the import-export wizard from one Edition to pull the data/schema to the other

Answer (score 1):

Install an instance of SQL 2008 R2 on one machine and SQL 2008 on another

Open SQL Server Management Studio R2

Select your source Database

Select Tasks>Generate Scripts.

Select 'Script entire database and all database objects', press 'Next'

Select 'Save to File' and click on the 'Advanced' button

Select 'Script for Server Version' and select the version you want: 200/2005/2008

Select 'Type of data to Script' and select Schema/Data/both

Click 'OK',Next and do it!

Copy the resulting file to the target machine with SQL 2008 [or whatever]

Log onto your SQL Management Studio and open the copied .sql file... be aware that there may be limitations on the file size.

There may also be issues with the order that the .SQL file inserts the data into the target database and if there are FK constraints in place, this could be an issue.... simply re-order the insert lists.

Once the .sql file is organised, parse it [just to sure], and then execute.

Comment: I thought I would run into hassel with that method but it took me only 10 Minutes to migrate a relatively complex database with that method. However, one should note that bigger databases will not work this way because the SQL management studio has problems handling sql files with several hundred MB.